How to calculate the projection
I'm creating a Data Engineer model in Snowflake where I need to calculate the projection at weekly level
Formula to calculate the projection : (left over supply in previous week) + (current week supply) - (current week demand)
TABLE



Supply
Demand
Week_Start_Date




1500
500
15-04-2024


0
500
22-04-2024


0
500
29-04-2024


0
500
06-05-2024


500
500
20-05-2024


0
500
03-06-2024


0
500
10-06-2024


0
500
17-06-2024


10000
500
24-06-2024


0
500
01-07-2024


0
500
08-07-2024



OUTPUT



Supply
Demand
Week_Start_Date
Proj




1500
500
15-04-2024
1000


0
500
22-04-2024
500


0
500
29-04-2024
0


0
500
06-05-2024
-500


500
500
20-05-2024
-500


0
500
03-06-2024
-1000


0
500
10-06-2024
-1500


0
500
17-06-2024
-2000


10000
500
24-06-2024
7500


0
500
01-07-2024
7000


0
500
08-07-2024
6500



Created some solution using LAG window function to calculate projection but not getting the desired output

I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?.

Use SUM() window function, over order by date:
select s.*, sum(supply - demand) over (order by Week_Start_Date)
from supply s;

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/DZWko6L1
